# How does the language in which Vim operates work?

Tags: vim, scripting

I've recently changed my text editor for coding to `vim`, I was using `Emacs` before and I have a pretty good understanding of how it works, mainly because I've read manuals and guides about `Emacs Lisp`, the language in which it is made. So I was wondering if there is such thing in `vim`; I want to understand the syntax of vim scripts like if I was learning a new language, but all I can find on the internet are guides on how to use the editor, how to change colors, how to map this and that...

Are there any resources that provide a formal introduction to the vim scripting language?

Comment: https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/

Comment: It's called VimL, or VimScript. There're published books on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chapter 41](https://vimhelp.org/usr_41.txt.html#usr_41.txt) of the Vim user manual thoroughly details the Vim scripting language, from basic variables and expressions all the way to full blown plugins.

You can open chapter 41 from within Vim with `:h usr_41.txt`.